# Heroku and facebook - cannot even clone my application to start working

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

Recently I've started working on a facebook app using Heroku and their tutorial is really extensive on the matter. However, when trying to clone my application to my machine, i get the following error:

Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I tried every solution I could find, resetting my key, uploading a new one, editting the key archive, but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

Does anyone have a different alternative to this?
Thanks

Im running Windows 7 Enterprise and my application is set to run on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you hold your keys try

```
heroku keys:add
```

> Without an argument, it will look for the key in the default place (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub). If you wish to use an alternate key file, specify it as an argument. Be certain you specify the public part of the key (the file ending in .pub). The private part of the key should never be transmitted to any third party, ever.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work aswell.

I ended up going a different route with my application than heroku, but thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

just wondering if you are Starting Command Prompt with Ruby? I had some problems with this aswell double check your ssh